Mission Control — Place Windows Close To Where They Are Positioned On Screen
Does software exist which replicates Mission Control, but instead of displaying the windows arbitrarily, it organizes the windows spatially close to their positions on the screen or displays them in a grid which doesn't or something else which is intuitive and doesn't change drastically when 1 window among many changes spaces?
